# How to sort list from FireStore

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my documents on FireStore, each one has a list of strings. When I'm displaying the document in app, I would like to sort them alphabetically. What I'm trying doesn't work.

```
var words = document['list'].cast<String>();
words.sort(); // Outputs 'null'
```

On inspection in the debugger, when I'm casting the list the object is of type `CastList`, but I can't find any info on this, and trying to create an object with that declared type tells me that it is an undefined class. So then I tried to specify the class that I'd like it to be:

```
List<String> words = document['list'].cast<String>();
```

But it still outputs `null` when I try to sort.

My collections look like this
 [image: Collection example]

I'm getting all of the documents inside of `lists` and displaying each of them in a listView.

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('lists').orderBy('releases').snapshots,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData)
      return const Center(child: Text('Loading...'));

      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
            _buildRow(context, snapshot.data.documents[index], index),
      );
    },
)

  Widget _buildRow(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document, int index) {
    var words = document['list'].cast<String>();
    var wordsString = words.toString();
    wordsString = wordsString.substring(1, wordsString.length - 1);

    return CheckboxListTile(
      title: Text(
        document['name'],
        style: _largerTextStyle,
      ),
      subtitle: Text(
        wordsString,
        style: _textStyle,
      ),
      value: _selectedIndices.contains(index),
      onChanged: (bool value) {
        setState(() {
          if (value) _selectedIndices.add(index);
          else _selectedIndices.remove(index);
        });
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: could you show us you data from firestore? (collection/document)

Comment: @diegoveloper Added an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work , don't need to call `cast`.

**Edit:**
I think you forgot to extract the data.

```
List words = document.data['list'];
words.sort();
```

Comment: That gives me null.

Comment: what's the name of your collection and how do you call? if you print this : document['list'] and gives you null, then your document is incorrect

Comment: I realized that the full hierarchy of the document might help, so I replaced the image. I also added the code I'm using to display the items.

Comment: It should be important to point out for anyone in the future coming here: the `sort()` method does not return a type, so it can't be called in the declare line. That was one of my problems.